# Move apps and configurations from 64-bit to 32-bit

Tags: 32-bit

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with a bunch of apps and configurations.

I want to move all that to another computer with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit.

Is this possible? Can I simply use TimeShift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup your current apps and config file

> ```
>  dpkg --get-selections "*" > app   # or use \*
>  debconf-get-selections > appconfig.txt
> ```

Install your app in new system.

> ```
>  dselect update
>  debconf-set-selections < appconfig.txt
>  dpkg --set-selections < app
>  apt-get -u dselect-upgrade    # or dselect install
> ```

Comment: I'm on a limited data plan. Is it possible to do it without downloading too much?

Comment: 64 bit application won't install in 32bit